# Emulador Android Genymotion se mantiene en estado "Booting"

Tags: genymotion

Estoy emulando Android 8.0 con Genymotion y de vez en cuando se queda el estado del dispositivo en "Booting" (aunque el emulador ya esté listo para usarse, el sistema funciona bien), como indica la imagen de abajo, y cuando está en ese estado Android Studio no lo reconoce como un emulador activo. Ni siquiera el 'Factory Reset' me soluciona el problema, hoy me funcionó reinstalar Genymotion, todo andaba bien y de repente quería emular de nuevo para seguir trabajando y volvió a aparecer.

Uso Genymotion para emular porque parece que ya nos vetaron completamente a los procesadores AMD para emular con el emulador stock de Android Studio 3+.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Valida que tengas actualizada la versión de tu OpenGL del controlador de tu video, yo tenía ese problema con la versión de OpenGL 1.1, aparentemente el Genymotion tiene incompatibilidad con versiones anteriores a la 2.0, así que actualicé el controlador de video NVidia y también se actualizó el OpenGL 3.3. Luego hice la prueba de bootear mi android virtual y logró cargar sin problemas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te dejo la herramienta para validar la versión del OpeNGL:

- http://www.realtech-vr.com/support/deeplink.php?SKU=15&target=UrlWin32

Espero te ayude.

Comment: Tengo OpenGL 4.6, pero es verdad que tenía una actualización del controlador de video de mi Radeon Vega 8.